# Load Average problems while serving 40M requests daily with php-fpm, nginx

Tags: nginx, freebsd, php-fpm, high-load

I have server with FreeBSD (16 cores with HT, SSD, 32Gb RAM) which is getting about 40M http requests daily. All requests are served by `nginx` + `php-fpm`.

[image]
[image]

At these graphs you see that we have a problems during traffic peak. *I'm not sysadmin, please explain me what is "Active connections", "Writing", "Waiting", "Reading" and why "Writing" increases when server is unable to serve requests quickly?*

Here are some more graphs with CPU,memory and Load Average.

[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see, nothing strange happens with CPU and memory, but Load Average also have a peak.

During this Load Average peak, I've noticed that there is a unserved queue on php-fpm.sock

`netstat -Lan | grep php-fpm
unix  2525/0/32246      /tmp/php-fpm.sock`

Number of members in queue is varying from 0 to 12000. When value is 0 - everything is fine and I'm getting http response in 60-100ms. When value is 5000-12000 is can take up to 3-10 seconds.

I've also checked if ther any unusual processes in `top`, but was unable to find anything.

Here is the `top` screenshot taken some minutes ago (right now everything is ok, no traffic peak):
[image]

My conclusion: according to CPU and memory graphs I can say that this server can serve more and more requests, but because of non-optimal work of php-fpm it is impossible during traffic peaks.

Any suggestions about how can this problem be solved?

Comment: Your CPU usage graph isn't tracking I/O wait, which is what you need to be looking at. You should fix this graph as soon as possible.

Comment: From this information it seems to be, that problem is around php. It can be useful to run top from cron every minute and then see states of php-fpm for time when problem was observed. Sample script to run from cron: https://gist.github.com/citrin/9742337#file-top-sh

Comment: @citrin, thank you! Will add now, let's see in the morning.

Comment: Yesterday I moved memcached from tcp to socket. Memcache totally disappeared from top. Today I havent seen any fails. Magic? I have to investigate more...